# Oracle declare variable syntax

Tags: oracle

Converting SQL to Oracle using “SQL Navigator” to test and running into syntax problems when declaring a variable.  Have read other related posts but nothing seems to be working.

Goal is to set a variable “strDate” to the current date as a string in this format YYYYMMDD.

Code I've tried is:

```
declare 
strDate := TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYYMONDD');

BEGIN
SELECT ColumnA a, ColumnB b, ColumnC c
from table1, table2
where stringcolumn = strDate;
end;
```

Error result is:
"ORA-06550; line 2 column 10: ...encountered the symbol "=" when expecting...."

Also tried:

```
var strDate varchar2(8)
exec :strDate := TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYYMONDD')

BEGIN
SELECT....;
end;
```

The query itself is a union query and I can run the individual 'parts' with hard coded values just fine.  Just can't seem to get it to accept variables for some reason.

Comment: The second version should work (except your format model is 9 chars, not 8; did you mean MM instead of MON here?); but how are you then using the variable in the query and what error do you get? I'm guessing you didn't refer to it as `:strDate` later...

Comment: Yes, I did mean MM - good catch thank you!  Corrected the :strDate vs :DateFrom in above

Comment: With the second version you can use the bind variable in the query as plain SQL, referring to it like `where stringcolumn = :strDate`, without the `begin/end`. It looks like maybe you added the PL/SQL wrapper to allow variables? No idea if SQL Navigator supports `var` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper syntax would be:

```
declare 
   DateFrom varchar2(20):= TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYYMONDD');
...
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `varchar2(9)`, rather than `date`; since it's being set with a `to_char`?

Comment: That worked in that it no longer throws the same error but now says, "an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement..."

Comment: @user1330259 - that's a completely separate issue; it isn't really fair to turn one question into several, or into a PL/SQL tutorial. The PL/SQL version of `select` is [documented here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/selectinto_statement.htm). It's not entirely clear if you really want this in a PL/SQL block though - depends what you want to happen with the data retrieved by the `select`.

Comment: Understood and apologize for the add-on.  Thank you for the reference.